# What can I write after self reference arrow?

Tags: scala, traits, self-reference

I understand what the result of a self type is as in

```
trait SpellChecker {
  self: RandomAccessSeq[char] =>
  ...
}
```

from http://www.markthomas.info/blog/92

As far as I understand it says "the object instantiated from this trait is also of type `RandomAccessSeq[char]`". Is that right?

My question: What can I write after the `=>` and what does it mean? I noticed I don't get a compiler error when writing `AnyRef` after the `=>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question: What can I write after the `=>`

Anything.

> and what does it mean?

It denotes the end of the self-type annotation. After that comes the normal trait body, just like as if the self-type annotation wasn't even there.

Answer (score 1):

```
trait A { ta: B =>
  // code
}
```

In this example `ta` is a `this` alias.  It's useful as a shorthand for `A.this`, for when you need to reference this code from somewhere else.

Because `ta` (i.e. this code) is of type `B`, all of `B`'s methods and member data are in scope and freely available.  This becomes a contract that the compiler will enforce: because `A` code can reference `B` code, `A` cannot be instantiated without `B` also in the mix.